# obj-C, why does this give me yesterdays date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I've been struggling with my function to return todays date, at as close to zero seconds, minutes and hours as possible. So I'm able to re-use the same date with various transactions.

However, I've now discovered that my function returns yesterdays date?

```
+ (NSDate *)makeAbsoluteNSDate:(NSDate*)datSource {

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:
           NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | 
            NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
            fromDate:datSource];
    [dateComponents setHour:0];
    [dateComponents setMinute:0];
    [dateComponents setSecond:0];

    NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
    [calendar release];

    return today;
}
```

Comment: First and obvious question will be have you checked your computer's TimeZone and Date??? please verify that both are same...

Comment: pleasse check your device's date or system's date..

Comment: I'm using the simulator and my macs date is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to get today's or yesterday's midnight in **your** time zone, you should get `NSDate` that points to adequate time in **GMT**. In my case -2 hours as my timezone is +0200, so for midnight of 2011-08-26 I'll get 2011-08-25 22:00.

You have to make sure that you're setting the right timezone for the `NSCalendar`, which is `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`.

My routine for getting the midnight in my time zone is:

```
+ (NSDate *)midnightOfDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    [components setTimeZone:[cal timeZone]];

    [components setHour:0];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];

    return [cal dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

So, after a *long* discussion in comments, here's a midday function:

```
+ (NSDate *)middayOfDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    [components setTimeZone:[cal timeZone]];

    [components setHour:12];
    [components setMinute:0];
    [components setSecond:0];

    return [cal dateFromComponents:components];
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried your code and for the current time on my machine is '2011-08-26 07:16:05 +0000' and this is what the datSource Value returns in debug. The function returns '2011-08-25 23:00:00 +0000' which I think is what your saying. What I really want from this function is '2011-08-26 whatever' ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you getting the time from? If it's from NSDate, it's not completely right. __NSDate doesn't hold timezone information__ - printing its contents always returns +0000. From the result of my function I see that your timezone is +0100 so the 2011-08-25 23:00 is right. If you really want midnight in GMT, I guess you need to set `[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]` instead of `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` and it should be fine.

Comment: I'm passing in 'date' NSDate *dateToday = [General makeAbsoluteNSDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: I need it to work world-wide based on the devices current date time.

Comment: `[NSDate date]` returns an `NSDate` that's created from the time in your system timezone. If your time is 09:36 +0100, you'll get 2011-08-26 08:36 +0000 in `NSDate`. It's overall important to always work on GMT. Local timezones are just for user output. So, does setting timezone to GMT in the function help?

Comment: Well this probable has come to light, as someone in Austrialia is seeing yesterday as the date. I'm not sure is GMT will work for her. :(

Comment: Well then, you have to give more context because it's not obvious, where the problem comes from. Who's that someone in Australia, where is she getting the date from etc.

Comment: I'm producing the date from NSDate *dateToday = [General makeAbsoluteNSDate:[NSDate date]]; in my app.

Comment: That's odd - it's still like that after you changed `systemTimeZone` into `timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0` ? Then maybe when creating the date you should do `[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]]`. This will give you NSDate with local time as GMT time. But I don't think that would be a correct solution to the whole timezone problem.

Comment: Well if I use timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0 this would cause problems not in GMT ? any further suggestions ?

Comment: I'll check that in the evening but I think that function will treat the date given as GMT and will create a GMT midnight. But then if you run [NSDate date] at, say, coming night's 01:00 (that is 2011-08-27 01:00) in time zone +0200, the resulting NSDate will give you 2011-08-26 23:00 +0000, so the midnight will be 2011-08-26 00:00 +0000. All that actually depends, what you want the midnight for.

Comment: I don't specifcally want midnight, but I need to get a date which will always be the same time for that day. So now will be a date with a neutral time for today. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So maybe instead of setting hour to 0 in my original code, set it to 12. This way it will always be noon of local time and midnight GMT the earliest, also for that day (for countries with +1200). For those with -1200 it will be next midnight though.

Comment: ok can you update your code please, i mean do I need to use gmt or systemtimezone etc ?

Comment: `systemTimeZone` will be fine. Code added!

Answer (score -2):

Use below function to get date for yesterday :

```
- (NSDate *)getDate:(NSDate *)date days:(NSInteger)days hours:(NSInteger)hours mins:(NSInteger)mins seconds:(NSInteger)seconds 
{
     NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
     NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSHourCalendarUnit |   NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:[[NSDate alloc] init]];

     days = (days*24) + hours; 
     [components setHour:days];
     [components setMinute:mins];
     [components setSecond:seconds];

     NSDate *returnDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
     return returnDate;
 }
```

To get yesterday date pass date = [NSDate date], day = -1, hours = 0 and mins = 0 as parameters in method calling.

Comment: I want today but I'm getting yesterday

Answer (score -3):

All you need is `[NSDate date]` for the current date & time.

Comment: Yeah but I want to strip out the seconds, minutes, and hours.